# Python digit sum function returns wrong digits on large numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function I wrote is fairly basic: It walks through every digit of `num` and prints it out. The remainder is then run again until the sample code is finished.

```
num = 1000000000000000000000000000001
while num > 0:
    curr = num % 10
    num = (num - curr) / 10
    print(curr)
```

The expected output of this would be `100000000000000000000000000001` (with linebreaks in between). However, it returns the following on the example above:

`1622442800000000000000000000001`

I suspect this has something to do with the limitations of the *long* datatype.

How could I handle this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are using float division.  I think you meant: `num = (num - curr) // 10`

Comment: you could use `print()` to see what you have in all variables.

Comment: @furas Afther the first loop, curr is 1 and num is 1e+29 (100000000000000000000000000000).

Because this is divisible without remainder, the next curr should be 0 and thus num should be 1e+28, but curr is 6. Without float division, it works perfectly, but using it seems to bring up some problems with large numbers.

Comment: `1e+29` is `float` number. If you would also use `print(type(num))` the you would see it. Using `print()` (and also also `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc. in some situations) you can see what program is doing and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see where can be the problem.

Comment: @furas I know, it works as described in the answer below. I also noticed that num was a float and used int() to convert it - it came out to 99999999999999991433150857216, which is obviously not the result that should occurr.

Comment: if you generate `float` then it is too late to make correction using `int()` :) . I only wanted to show that `print()` is simply (and maybe primitive) method to search where is the problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because in Python 3, `/` means "floating-point" division. Try `//` instead.

Comment: You are correct, I overlooked this. Thanks!